# Retrofit :How to pass Array with String parameter in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to send a request to the Google GeoCode API using Retrofit. The service interface looks like this:

```
 @GET("api/job/costestimate?stops[0][latitude]=40.72822&stops[0][longitude]=-73.70667000000003&stops[0][type]=pickup&stops[1][latitude]=40.7382953&stops[1][longitude]=-73.64537630000001&stops[1][type]=dropoff")
    Call<GetCostEstimateResponse> getCostEstimate(@Query("stops[{id}][latitude]") GetCostEstimateRequest getCostEstimateRequest, @Header("X-ACCESS-TOKEN") String xAccessToken);
```

How can i pass this kind of Structure parameter through Retrofit

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I have multiple stops,each stop contain latitude,longitude and type of stop.,So i want to pass parameter like stops[0][latitude] with Api.